# Sumfony console, как читать stdin

Tags: php, консоль, symfony

Пишу простое консольное приложение с командами на основе классов `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command`.

Возникла необходимость читать ввод через пайп, пришлось сделать вот так:
`$params = stream_get_contents(fopen("php://stdin", "r"));`.
Вопрос, есть ли уже в `symfony/console` реализация такого чтения?

Answer (score 0):

Хотел загуглить и попал на этот вопрос.

Почитал код, в 4.3 такого нет. В `bin/console` создаётся `ArgvInput`, который и попадает в `execute` команды. Читайте STDIN.